# No answer being displayed. Any ideas?

Tags: java, math, syntax, percentage

```
 double overallMark = ((20/100) * homeworkAverage) + ((80/100) * examinationAverage);
```

Is something wrong with my syntax? I'm getting 0.0 as an answer :(

I need to add 20% of homeworkAverage to 80% of examinationAverage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing integer division with `20/100`, and in Java, dividing `int`s yields an `int`, the truncated quotient.

Cast one of them as a `double` or use `double` literals to force floating-point division:

```
((double) 20 / 100)
```

or

```
(20.0 / 100.0)
```

... and similarly you'll need to change `(80/100)`.

Answer (score 2):

`20/100` becomes `0` because of integer division.

Try changing it to `20.0/100.0` so that doubles are used instead.